# Suppress Openssl output during grep

Tags: bash, grep

I often use `grep` for openssl results when testing TLS security. For example:

```
$ openssl s_client -tls1_2 -connect 172.11.15.32:443 </dev/null | grep 'IS s'
depth=0 C = US, ST = asd, O = Billing, CN = asdasd, emailAddress = root@asdasd
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = asd, O = Billing, CN = asdasd, emailAddress = root@asdasd
verify return:1
DONE
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
```

However, the issue is, that no matter what I grep for, output always contains these (or similar) lines in the beginning:

```
depth=0 C = US, ST = asd, O = Billing, CN = asdasd, emailAddress = root@asdasd
    verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
    verify return:1
    depth=0 C = US, ST = asd, O = Billing, CN = asdasd, emailAddress = root@asdasd
    verify return:1
```

Is it possible to somehow suppress these messages and receive only grep results as one would expect?

Comment: This is probably because most of its output goes to stderr, which goes through without `grep` making any action to it (it just checks stdout). Just redirect it using `openssl 2>/dev/null` and then grep accordingly.

Comment: @fedorqui That was fast, and indeed that solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As indicated in comments, the problem is that the command `openssl` displays part of its output through `stderr`. Then, this will show no matter what you pipe.

So if you want to just show what `grep` has filtered to you, you have to previously redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null` so that it does not "jump the pipe":

```
openssl ... 2>/dev/null | grep 'IS s'
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

See another example of this:

```
$ touch hello
$ ls hello adlsfjaskldf
ls: cannot access adlsfjaskldf: No such file or directory  # stderr
hello                                                      # stdout
```

Let's grep, where everything appears:

```
$ ls hello adlsfjaskldf | grep hello
ls: cannot access adlsfjaskldf: No such file or directory  # stderr
hello                                                      # stdout
```

Let's grep but redirect stderr beforehand:

```
$ ls hello adlsfjaskldf 2>/dev/null | grep hello
hello                                      # no "ls: cannot access..." here
```

Comment: What if you're trying to grep the output of `openssl enc -help`? Redirecting stderr doesn't seem to do it. For example: `openssl enc -help 2>/dev/null | grep "pbkdf2"` should return `-pbkdf2             Use password-based key derivation function 2`, but it returns nothing.

Comment: Try redirecting stderr to stdout (instead of /dev/null) prior to grepping: `openssl enc -help 2>&1 | grep "pbkdf2"`. Worked for me when grepping openssl help, maybe it would work for others too :) `&1` is the reference to stdout just like `/dev/null` is the reference for null device.